# How to build an internal search engine?

Tags: c#, wpf, search

I am looking in a way to build an internal search engine that gonna search transactions depending on criterias. 
The problem i have is more criteria mean more checks.. so if there is 6 criteria.. i almost have to do 6 x 6 = 36 ELSE in an IF statement. That huge.. i am pretty sure there some other way to do it.

Explanation : If i have an object which have A,B,C,D,E,F i have to check if

```
A,B,C,D,E NOT F
A,B,C,D, NOT E, F
A,B,C, NOT D, E, F
etc..
```

So how i could handle this ? (I am using C# with WPF)

EDIT: Here more details.

- This is code not SQL.
- The number of criteria that must be evaluated depend on the user.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some more details, like what kind of criteria you have for this? How are they specified to the search engine, etc. That would make it easier to answer better.

Comment: Your calculation of how many IF statements you'll need is incorrect. You'd really need 2^6=64 statements, not 6^2. If you wanted both A="blah" and A NOT ="blah" then you'd need 2^7=128 checks. (hm, is this right?)

Comment: (Obviously I'm not suggesting you actually hardcode 128 if statements)

Comment: @Brian i hope so that why i asked here lol but yeah i did a mistake its exactly 64 statements i need.. but i can't hardcode this.. that would be insane.

Comment: @Lasse I have an object and a search engine where you can enter 6 criterias. You must be able to evaluate those 6 criterias to determine if a transaction is part of the results.

Comment: Are you going to do it in SQL, or in code? Do you have to evaluate all 6 in one big honking expression, or can you evaluate them one by one, as long as the end result is the same? Do you support parenthesis? ie. `(A OR B) AND (C OR D)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this kind of thing is to build some kind of expression tree. This might just be List of criteria objects. Each object has a "check" method to say whether or not the element passes the test. You can build this list at run time, then use it to check every candidate.

Or look at LINQ. It's perfectly suited.

Comment: Interesting. Well i was thinking about making a object for this but i though this would lead to the exact same problematic. But maybe not.. will have to look at this.

Comment: There's all kinds of ways to do it. The trick is to remember that you can build and use data structures at run time. Don't be constrained by thinking 'statically'.

Comment: This solution work perfectly. Thanks! you saved me a lots of time!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're building a sql command. Typically we would just put a series of IF/CASE statements (one for each possible parameter) that would append SQL. But these days, you can use LINQ:

```
var q = from c in Customers select c;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Name))
    q = q.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(param.Name));

if(param.CustID.HasValue)
    q = q.Where(c => c.ID == param.CustID);

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param.CustAddr))
    q = q.Where(c => c.Addr.Contains(param.CustAddr));

//use your results!
```

Comment: it should be `q = q.Where....`, as otherwise you're just throwing away the new `IQueryable` object.

Comment: So the idea is basically to eliminate the transactions at each step (those that doesnt comply with the criterias) with LINQ queries ?